# Parsley js remote config. Error browser dev console

Tags: parsley.js

I followed the [Custom remote validators](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html) documentation

I have `<script href="parsley.remote.js"></script>` before `<script href="parsley.js"></script>` just before the end of html body and I'm seeing the following message on the console of Chrome Developer Tools:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined(anonymous function) @ parsley.remote.js:267(anonymous function) @ parsley.remote.js:271

Part of paryley.remote.js code :

```
window.Parsley.on('form:submit', function () {
  this._remoteCache = {};
});
```

On Firebug the error console message is

> TypeError: window.Parsley is undefined 
>   window.Parsley.on('form:submit', function () {

[A small lab just a test html page with source dist js parsley](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3K-9i5TgtYMfk1wcmV6N09PVjdkQlA4Q2J4bUptRHJvT0RKTlFWY2hqcTAxQlpVY0lZV3c&usp=sharing)

If I invert file reference `parsley.remote.js` and `parsley.js`, the error disappears, but according to the documentation, it's not the right way.

Comment: Mmm, that's a bug. You need only include one, but `remote` is broken. Including the non remote is a good workaround until I fix that.

Answer (score 0):

It's was bug, fixed in 2.1.3+.

Only include the `remote` version (assuming you need it).

Comment: I'm on version 2.1.3 and still get the same error. I'm loading parsley with requirejs. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try updating to the latest version?

Comment: Isn't 2.1.3 the latest stable release ?

Comment: version 2.2.0-rc4 fixed the issue, thanks! What's the ETA for prod release?

Comment: Yesterday ;-)  the rcs are production ready, I just wasn't sure about API of new methods.